# Spring Boot, Session Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I have some resources that I have in a Spring Boot setup that a user needs to have a session for.

Right now, these endpoints in need of defense all look like this.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/SomeEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<SomePacket> Foot(@RequestBody Dummy dummy,
                                                           HttpServletRequest request,
                                                           HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, RestSessionException {
    if (session.getAttribute("clientId") == null) {
        throw new RestSessionException("No Client");
    }
```

Each.and.every.one.of.them...

What I would like to do is reduce the amount of duplication throughout my codebase with checking for a "clientId" on the session. I've read about WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters, but they seem to revolve more around the fluent interface, and not so much around retrieving session values.

Does anyone know how I can check session properties for certain endpoints in a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of adding in every controller you can use interceptor instead which can be configured only for some URL or for every request.

Comment: I like the interceptor a lot. I think in going to try that!

Answer (score 0):

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` is implementation of spring security and which provides functionality for authorisation and authentication for your endpoints. For more info about WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter read [this](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RC1/reference/html/jc.html)

Your requirement can simply achieve by adding filter and applying required logic of checking clientId in doFilter method.